# Django REST Framework hyperlink URL failing to resolve

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set up hyperlinking in my Django REST Framework API, and for the life of me I can't find out where my error is.

My model:

```
class Franchise(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # Other fields
```

My serializer

```
class FranchiseListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='franchise_details',
        lookup_field='id',
        lookup_url_kwarg='franchiseid'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Franchise
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url')
```

My URLs:

```
url(r'^db/franchise/$', views.franchise_index, name='db_franchise_index'),
url(r'^db/franchise/(?P<franchiseid>[0-9]+)/$', views.franchise_details, name='db_franchise_details')
```

Note that this is an included url conf, all my api functionality goes within an /api/ url

My views:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def franchise_index(request, format=None):
    franchise_list = Franchise.objects.all()
    serializer = FranchiseListSerializer(franchise_list, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def franchise_details(request, franchiseid, format=None):
    franchise = Franchise.objects.get(id=franchiseid)
    serializer = FranshiseDetailSerializer(franchise)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note that `FranshiseDetailSerializer` seen above works just fine.

Summary:

- URL /api/db/franchise/ goes to the view `franchise_index`, which returns data serialized by `FranchiseListSerializer`.
- URL /api/db/franchise/`<franchiseid>`/ goes to the view `franchise_details`, which returns data serialized by `FranchiseDetailSerializer` (Works fine)

As you can see, I have added a url field to `FranchiseListSerializer`, which I supposed to link to the corresponding franchise details page. Before I added the url field, the serializer only returned `id` and `name`, which was the correct and expected behaviour at the time.

When I go to /api/db/franchise/ now, I get the error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/db/franchise/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "franchise_details". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Following this hint, I set up the arguments in the `url` field of `FranchiseListSerializer`, and as far as I can tell, they are correct. I have checked and double checked the DRF documentation, [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer), [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield) and [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/#hyperlinking-our-api), but have found no solution.

Following other similar issues on Stackoverflow, I tried changing `view_name='franchise_details'` to `view_name='api:franchise_details'` (the name of the Django app the relevant files are in) and `view_name='api:franchise_details-detail'`, but to no avail.

Any and all help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: In urls you have view_name `'db_franchise_details'` but in the serializer you have `'franchise_details'` hence the mismatch.

Comment: Ahh, the documentation seem to say otherwise, at least how I read it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AKS's promting, I figured it out. `view_name` is actually the name of the URL, not the view. From the way I read the documentation (and the fact that it is `view_name` not `url_name`), it seemed to say that it was supposed to be the name of the view.

I had actually tried using `view_name='db_franchise_details'` (my urls name) before, but that did not work. After AKS promted my with that comment, I tried again, and also tried using `view_name='api:db_franchise_details'`, which does work!